# How to select DOM element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have a function in javascript that draws images on a random canvas

I select my `img` source using javascript default selector,then draw part this image on a desired canvas

I want to use jquery to select my img object, but when I replace `var img =document ...` with `var img=$("#karajan")`, but the function do not draw image on canvases

Also I've tried `var img=$("#karajan").text()  .... $("#karajan").val() .... $("#karajan").html()` but none of them did not work

```
    function drawImage() {

        var img = document.getElementById("karajan");
        var arr = getRandomArray();
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                var dx = ((j == 0) ? 0 : j * 150 + j * 10);
                var dy = ((i == 0) ? 0 : i * 150 + i * 10);
                var k = i * 3 + j;
                if (k > 7) continue;

                getCanvas(arr[k] - 1).drawImage(img, j * 150, i * 150, 150, 150, 0, 0, 150, 150);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `$("#karajan").get()`, or, because it's an ID and therefore should be unique, `$('#karajan')[0]`

Comment: `$("#karajan")` returns a jQuery object that contains a DOM element (assuming there is one with that id), it doesn't return a DOM element like `getElementById()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn I know and my question is how could I obtain DOM element?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy $('#karajan')[0] was the answer, thanks bro

Comment: Yes, I was just providing some extra information beyond what Ohgodwhy said - your question didn't make it clear that you already knew what that information, especially when you said you were trying `.val()` and so forth. Really all of that canvas stuff is completely irrelevant, you could've just said "How do I obtain a reference to a DOM element with jQuery so that I can use the element with non-jQuery code?" (or similar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `$("#karajan").get(0)`. or `$("#karajan")[0]`.